# BST range search

Tags: tree, binary-search, common-lisp

I'd like some input on my implementation of `bst-range`, which follows below.

Before we can get to bst-range, we first need some setup code to build the BST.

(You can imagine that node label `count` didn't exist if you want, as it's not used for range search).

### Setup

```lisp
(defstruct
  (node (:print-function
          (lambda (n s d)
            (format s "#<~A ~A ~A ~A>" (node-elt n) (node-l n) (node-r n) (node-count n)))))
  elt count (l nil) (r nil))

(defun node-size (node)
  (if (null node)
      0
      (node-count node)))

(defun bst-insert (obj bst <)
  (if (null bst)
      (make-node :elt obj :count 1)                       
      (let ((elt (node-elt bst)))
        (if (eql obj elt)
            bst                                           
            (if (funcall < obj elt)
                (let ((new-l (bst-insert obj (node-l bst) <)))
                  (make-node
                    :elt elt
                    :count (+ (node-size new-l) (node-size (node-r bst)) 1)
                    :l new-l
                    :r (node-r bst)))
                (let ((new-r (bst-insert obj (node-r bst) <)))
                  (make-node
                    :elt elt
                    :count (+ (node-size (node-l bst)) (node-size new-r) 1)
                    :l (node-l bst)
                    :r new-r)))))))
```

The above code was the subject of my [earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/230855/bst-with-node-count) and is working fine. It's assumed here.

### Range search

I implemented `bst-range` by translating the code [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html) (where it is referred to as the function `keys`), and described [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/) under the heading "range search".

```lisp
(defun bst-range (min max bst <)
  (if (null bst)
      nil
      (let ((elt (node-elt bst)))
        (when (funcall < min elt)
          (bst-range min max (node-l bst) <))
        (when (and (or (eql min elt)
                       (funcall < min elt))
                   (or (eql max elt)
                       (funcall < elt max)))
          (setf *result* (cons elt *result*)))
        (when (funcall < elt max)
          (bst-range min max (node-r bst) <)))))
```

It runs like this

```lisp
(defparameter *bst* nil)                   ; [1]
(dolist (x '(1 6 3 7 21 40))
  (setf *bst* (bst-insert x *bst* #'<)))


[25]> (defparameter *result* nil)          ; [2]
*RESULT*

[26]> (bst-range 5 10 *bst* #'<)           ; [3]
NIL

[27]> *result*                             ; [4]
(7 6)

[28]> 

;; [1] first build a BST
;; [2] use global var to store result of range search (seems ugly)
;; [3] call the range search
;; [4] see the result
;;     Here we are searching for all the entries in the bst between
;;     5 and 10, which are, as we can see from what we inserted, just 6 & 7.
```

### Questions

1. Is there a nice way to accumulate the result via an optional parameter?
   I tried (and failed) on that, which is why I ended up with defparameter. Not certain the accumulator is the right path for this function though. Is it? If not, why?
2. Would some datastructure for result other than a list be better here?
   If so, why?

### Update

Here's another idea for `bst-range`, implemented via a higher order function.

```lisp
(defun bst-traverse (fn bst)
  (when bst
    (bst-traverse fn (node-l bst))
    (funcall fn (node-elt bst))
    (bst-traverse fn (node-r bst))))


(defun bst-range (min max bst <)
  (bst-traverse (lambda (elt)
                  (when (<= min elt max)
                    (princ elt)))           ; [1]
                bst)) 

;; [1] We need to enqueue onto some ds here instead of princ.
;;     Wondering how best to organise this code...
```